# django haystack / whoosh: find records with umlauts / diaeresis, with a plain ascii query

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have umlauts/diaeresis and other special characters in my haystack (ä, ö, ü, é, è, ç, etc.). They seem to be indexed well, and are found if searched, as they are in the index.

Example: Searching for "Häberli" returns the all records containing it.

**What I want:** Searching for "Haberli" should return all those records as well. I am currently using the `SearchQuerySet.auto_query()`. I didn't find any hints in the docs.

**Bonus:** Searching for "Haeberli" should return those as well.

I'm using django 1.8.5, haystack 2.4.1 and whoosh 2.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `ascii folding token filter` with elastic search: follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html) link.

EDIT: reading your question again... with Whoosh you want to use `whoosh.analysis.CharsetFilter` which does character folding.

Here is a gist with the full solution: [link](https://gist.github.com/gregplaysguitar/1727204).

Comment: so easy. it looks. will check and let you know!

Comment: elsewise just knowing the term ascii folding should point you in the right direction when you know what to search for!

Comment: works for `a` and `ä`, but not for `ae` and `ä` (which is quite common in german). would adapting the `accent_map` (see your gist) help, or do I need another solution for this?

Comment: It should work for the actual æ character, if you want to combine ae im sure there are some filter that does that too.